# Self deleting button

Tags: delphi, button, panel, free, self

I have a TScrollBox with a bunch of TPanels with some TButtons generated at runtime.
I need to delete the TPanel when one TButton is clicked but doing that in OnClick end in an access violation...

```
procedure TMainForm.ButanClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vParentPanel: TPanel;
begin
  if (string(TButton(Sender).Name).StartsWith('L')) then
  begin
    TButton(Sender).Caption := 'YARE YARE DAZE';
  end
  else
  begin
    vParentPanel := TPanel(TButton(Sender).GetParentComponent());
    TheScrollBox.RemoveComponent(vParentPanel);
    vParentPanel.Destroy();
    // access violation but the panel is removed
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  vPanel: TPanel;
  vButton: TButton;
begin
  for i := 0 to 20 do
  begin
    vPanel := TPanel.Create(TheScrollBox);
    vPanel.Align := alTop;
    vPanel.Parent := TheScrollBox;

    vButton := TButton.Create(vPanel);
    vButton.Align := alLeft;
    vButton.Parent := vPanel;
    vButton.Name := 'L_butan' + IntToStr(i);
    vButton.OnClick := ButanClick;

    vButton := TButton.Create(vPanel);
    vButton.Align := alRight;
    vButton.Parent := vPanel;
    vButton.Name := 'R_butan' + IntToStr(i);
    vButton.OnClick := ButanClick;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The debugger show that the access violation is in Vcl.Controls on a mouse event, so i tried to click the button with the keyboard and theres no access violation.

Comment: Don't delete the panel in the event handler of a control on the panel. Rather have the OnClick of the button post a message, then in response to the message delete the panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot safely destroy the parent `TPanel` (or the `TButton` itself) from inside the `TButton`'s `OnClick` event.  The VCL still needs access to the `TPanel`/`TButton` for a beat after the event handler exits.  So, you need to delay the destruction until after the handler exits.  The easiest way to do that is to use [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) to call `TObject.Free()` on the `TPanel`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.ButanClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vButton: TButton;
begin
  vButton := TButton(Sender);
  if vButton.Name.StartsWith('L') then
  begin
    vButton.Caption := 'YARE YARE DAZE';
  end
  else
  begin
    TThread.ForceQueue(nil, vButton.Parent.Free);
  end;
end;
```

The `TPanel` will remove itself from the `TScrollBox` during its destruction. You do not need to handle that step manually.

Comment: This is slick! :)

Comment: Got an accession violation again but the code is the same as yesterday and was working ?!?

Comment: I've used this kind of code in the past without issue.  The only thing that could cause an AV in it is if something else destroys the `TPanel` before the `TThread.ForceQueue()` request is processed. Otherwise, your AV would have to be caused by something else that is unrelated to this code. If you run your code inside the debugger, you should be able to see where the AV is happening, and trace back up the call stack to see what is triggering it.

Comment: So i made a blank project and i copypasted the code... Found out that is the TStyleManager in the dpr file, removing the style thers no more access violations even if i try to free the button directly. I think that the access violation is due to some message of the mouse in combination with the stylemanager

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? If it is a recent version, then you should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: 10.4 Community Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with **Renate Schaaf** answer:

```
...
const
WM_REMOVEPANEL = WM_USER + 9001;
procedure ButanClick(Sender: TObject);
procedure OnCustomMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_REMOVEPANEL;

...
procedure TMainForm.ButanClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vParentPanel: TPanel;
begin
  if (string(TButton(Sender).Name).StartsWith('L')) then
  begin
    TButton(Sender).Caption := 'YARE YARE DAZE';
  end
  else
  begin
    // SendMessage = access violation again because it wait the return
    // while PostMessage return istantly
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_REMOVEPANEL, 0, THandle(@Sender));
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.OnCustomMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  vButton: TButton;
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_REMOVEPANEL) then
  begin
    vButton := TButton(Pointer(Msg.LParam)^);
    ShowMessage(vButton.Name);
    TheScrollBox.RemoveComponent(vButton.GetParentComponent());
    TPanel(vButton.GetParentComponent()).Destroy();
    Msg.Result := 1;
  end
  else
    Msg.Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: `THandle(@Sender)` need to be `LPARAM(Sender)` instead, and then `TButton(Pointer(Msg.LParam)^)` needs to be `TButton(Msg.LParam)`.  You need to send the *value* of the `Sender` pointer to the message handler, not the *address* of the `Sender` pointer. The *address* won't be valid anymore once the `OnClick` handler exits, and since `PostMessage()` is asynchronous, the message handler will execute after the `OnClick` handler exits (which is the whole point of this exercise).